# Is there a naming convention for the type parameter in generic typed code (bracy flavoured)

Tags: c#, generics, typescript

Is there a naming convention for type parameters on generic typed code?

I'm doing some TypeScript now but it has the same style of type parametrisation as C#, Java, AS3 etc.

I see most common used `T`, als in:

```
interface Container<T> {
    getContent(): List<T>;
}
```

But what if you need more then 1 type? I see single letters, usually T, U and V. Sometimes K, V are used for the key and value of mappings.

Surely there must be a best practice for this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A widely adopted standard is `T1`, `T2`, `T3`, etc, if there is more than 1 *unpurposed* generic type parameter (that is, where the intended purpose of the parameters is not known from within the class itself, so you can't really give them a more descriptive name).

See `Tuple` class, as a good example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx).

`Tuple` has the following forms:

```
Tuple<T1>
Tuple<T1, T2>
Tuple<T1, T2, T3>
Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4>
Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>
Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6>
Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7>
```

Using anything else in cases like this will probably be confusing to anyone reading your code. On seeing `T1`, `T2`, `T3`, everyone will know they are generic type parameters.

However, in the case of generic parameters with *predefined purposes*, specific names are more appropriate. As pointed out by @AlexeiLevenkov, for return values it's also very common to use `TResult` to distinguish it from any other type arguments. `Func` provides a good example of this, as described in the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), with example below:

```
public delegate TResult Func<in T, out TResult>(
    T arg
)
```

Along similar lines, `Dictionary` uses `<TKey, TValue>` as its type parameters. That's because it needs to be immediately clear which is which. The class code doesn't know *what* `TKey` or `TValue` are, but it *does* know they represent keys and values, so it make sense to put that information in the parameter name.

Microsoft have some (old!) naming guidelines [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2005/12/02/497340.aspx), where they cover another interesting case. They suggest indicating *constraints* placed on a type parameter in the name of the parameter itself, as follows:

```
public interface ISessionChannel<TSession> where TSession : ISession
{
    TSession Session { get; }
}
```

In this case, because the generic parameter is constrained to be an `ISession`, it makes sense to communicate this by naming the parameter `TSession`.

Comment: +1: this kind is common for arguments that used uniformly, additionally one can name types with more meaning as don for  `Func<T1,T2,T3, TResult>` - special case for result as it would be almost impossible to guess if first or last type signifies the result.

Comment: `Dictionary<TKey, TValue> Class` would be another good example that uses descriptive names from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This approach I think is more common than T1, T2, etc.

Comment: This is first time I see numbered type parameters. But makes sense that it is less confusing (partially why I asked I guess). Specialisation like TKey, TValue, TResult all look fine too. Lets see if some more info turn up before I accept this :)